# Duda slider en página HTML

Tags: html, slider

estoy intentando colocar un slider en una página, mi duda es cómo puedo hacer para que en la versión móvil de 320 se coloque en toda la pantalla, y no solo en un espacio, espero me puedan ayudar, soy nueva haciendo sliders

Así es como me gustaría que se viera en la versión de 320
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es cómo se ve =(
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El  código que utilizo para mi slider es este:

```
  <div id="home" class="slider-area">
        <div class="bend niceties preview-2">
            <div id="ensign-nivoslider" class="slides">
                <div class="bend niceties preview-2">
                    <div id="ensign-nivoslider" class="slides">
                        <img src="assets/img/slider/slider1.jpg" alt="" title="#slider-direction-1" />
                        <img src="assets/img/slider/slider2.jpg" alt="" title="#slider-direction-2" />
                        <img src="assets/img/slider/slider3.jpg" alt="" title="#slider-direction-3" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y el que me gusta cómo se ve lo saque de una plantilla pero la verdad no entiendo muy bien ya que están escritos de diferentes maneras =( espero alguien me pueda apoyar

Answer (score -1):

```css
body{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container{
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 30px;
}

ul, li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.slider{
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
}

ul.slider li {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    transition: opacity .5s;
    background:#fff;
}

ul.slider li img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

ul.slider li:first-child {
    opacity: 1; /*Mostramos el primer <li>*/
}

ul.slider li:target {
    opacity: 1; /*Mostramos el <li> del enlace que pulsemos*/
}

.menu{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.menu li{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li a{
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  
  <ul class="slider">
    <li id="slide1">
      <img src="https://www.revistaneo.com/sites/default/files/inline-images/5_0.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li id="slide2">
      <img src="https://www.revistaneo.com/sites/default/files/2020-10/fondos-padres.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li id="slide3">
      <h1>wenas</h1>
      <p>wenas</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#slide1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#slide2">2</a>
    </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#slide3">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Básicamente en html se agrega una lista y en cada `<li>a</li>` se agrega el elemento que quieres mostrar, luego, otra lista abajo con los botones que muestran un elemento diferente cada uno, en css necesitamos poscisción absoluta, `ul.slider li:target { opacity: 1; /*Mostramos el <li> del enlace que pulsemos*/ }`
esto nos lleva a la imagen del botón que hayamos pulsado `ul.slider li:first-child { opacity: 1; /*Mostramos el primer <li>*/ }`
esto es para que muestre el primero cuando abras la pagina

Comment: si te sirvió pícale en la palomita :D

Comment: Saludos, tu respuesta quedaría mucho mas completa si explicas a OP tu código y como lo que propones resuelve su problema. Por favor lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). ;)